# Business Layer and entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to modify a single table in sqlserver via entity framework, but had no luck so far.

The table has one uniqueidentifier ID, one first name and one last name.

I actually want to perform the databinding on the database and I want the program to have interaction with the user so the user will modify the data base via a UI or console.

Comment: 2 years of C# and you can't find one of the many tutorials that cover this exactly?

Comment: You clearly haven't tried very hard. I recommend you do some research.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a guide for this topic here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/19/absolue-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework.aspx

this example covers the creation of database objects inside the framework, how to link to it,  standard CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete operations etc...)

And for the rest: may google.com be a good friend for a first impression and start. When you have specific questions, go to stackoverflow.com, people are nice here, but you gotta try first and not just ask how EF works.

Comment: BTW, search for guide entity framework and you're off